# Cocoapod fails to build on Travis-CI - "expected a type"

Tags: objective-c, continuous-integration, llvm, cocoapods, travis-ci

**Objective**: Build a cocoapod with CI support through travis-ci and coveralls.

**Sub Objective**: Keep git repo cleared of `Pods/`, while still including `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock`

Referenced repo: [SRRandomUser](https://github.com/spacedrabbit/SRRandomUser)

*note: while indeed there exists a simple workaround solution (just removing `Pod/` from my `.gitignore`, I ask this question because it will likely be helpful to understand this issue for future work.*

---

Here is the situation I find myself in:

1. Using [FSNetworking](https://github.com/foursquare/FSNetworking) for network requests.

   - One of its classes, [`FSNData`](https://github.com/foursquare/FSNetworking/blob/master/src/FSNData.m), has a class method [`withImage:jpegQuality:fileName:`](https://github.com/foursquare/FSNetworking/blob/master/src/FSNData.m#L70) that accepts a `UIImage` and `CGFloat` as parameters.
   - Building this file without adding `@import` for `UIKit` and `CoreGraphics` results in a compiler error of `expected a type` with reference to the `UIImage` and `CGFloat` parameters
   - Locally, this is not a problem because I can add the module `@import`s, however since I am not committing the entirety of the `Pods/` directory, these changes don't get pushed
2. Travis received the build and attempts to build, but since the `FSNData` doesn't have `CoreGraphics` or `UIKit` imported, when Travis goes to build the project, [it throws the error in `SRRandomUserGenerator`](https://travis-ci.org/spacedrabbit/SRRandomUser/builds/60486385#L1581) since that class is `#import`ing the affected `FSNData` class:

> ✗ Compile SRRandomUserGenerator.m (73 ms)

```
In file included from /Users/travis/build/spacedrabbit/SRRandomUser/Random Strangers/SRRandomUser/SRRandomUser/SRRandomUserAPIManager.h:10:
In file included from /Users/travis/build/spacedrabbit/SRRandomUser/Random Strangers/SRRandomUser/../../Pods/Headers/Public/FSNetworking/FSNConnection.h:36:
/Users/travis/build/spacedrabbit/SRRandomUser/Random Strangers/SRRandomUser/../../Pods/Headers/Public/FSNetworking/FSNData.h:42:18: error: expected a type
+ (id)withImage:(UIImage*)image jpegQuality:(CGFloat)quality fileName:(NSString*)fileName;
                    ^
/Users/travis/build/spacedrabbit/SRRandomUser/Random Strangers/SRRandomUser/../../Pods/Headers/Public/FSNetworking/FSNData.h:42:46: error: expected a type
+ (id)withImage:(UIImage*)image jpegQuality:(CGFloat)quality fileName: (NSString*)fileName;
                                               ^
2 errors generated.
```

---

So, my questions are:

- How do I either silence that warning so that the build runs anyhow or
- How do I get that Pod to include the correct frameworks for building?

Many thanks in advance, SO.

Comment: Check this post: https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/. Maybe can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana really great post, and a topic that's very lacking in documentation. I don't think it directly addresses the problem I'm having, but I think my next steps on this would be to play around with the `script` portion of `travis.yml` in a similar way you write about. For me, it seems that built-in libraries in my project aren't being linked for the CocoaPod to use... somehow. Truthfully, I haven't really looked at this in a long while until your comment got me thinking about it again :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to search for the framework you need via Cocoapods.org. If you're using Cocoapods it usually means that it's been linked to your project (so there's really no way to silence the error, especially in this case where it seems that the framework you're using depends on other frameworks)